# Save ListView selected Item in a Fragment having a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to make some kind of test app in which you can change from one question to another swiping left or right. So, I have a FragmentActivity, a ViewPager and a FragmentPagerAdapter.

Each new page the FragmentPagerAdapter instantiates a new Fragment using the same Layout which has a ListView on it, up to 5 total pages. Then an ArrayAdapter fills the ListView with 4 CheckedTextViews, when the user selects one, the background changes.

The problem is that, when you swipe from one question to another, the selected item is lost, and when the user swipes back to the previous question the item is no longer selected.

I am newbie with fragments, but when I do the same using checkboxes directly inflated from the xml, their selected state isn't lost when swiping.

Here is some code:

**FragmentActivity onCreate():**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        //Getting the array of questions.
        res = getResources();
        questions = res.getStringArray(R.array.questions_1);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the five
        // questions of the app.
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the FragmentPagerAdapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

**FragmentPagerAdapter:**

```
    public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
            //Number of pages
    return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        ArrayListFragment fragment = ArrayListFragment
                .newInstance(position);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();

        return getString(R.string.title_section) + " " + (position + 1);

    }
}
```

**Fragment Class:**

```
public static class ArrayListFragment extends Fragment {
            //Current Page number.
    int mNum;
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    ListView list;

    /**
     * Create a new instance of ArrayListFragment, providing "num" as an
     * argument.
     */
    static ArrayListFragment newInstance(int num) {
        ArrayListFragment f = new ArrayListFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    /**
     * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;

    }

    /**
     * The Fragment's UI is a textview showing a question and the ListView with               
             * the four possible answers.
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container,
                false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    //Set the Question
        ((TextView) tv).setText(questions[mNum]);
        //Get que ListView and fill it.
        list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item, myStringArray));
                    //Select an item.
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                arg1.setSelected(true);
            }

        });


        return v;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it should not remember your choice. Once you leave the page it probably will be destroyed. By default ViewPager save 3 pages only (Current one, on left side and on right side). But you can save user choose in host activity. For this you will need to create an interface with, lets say, function `public void onAnswerSelected(int questionId, int answerId)` and implement it in `Activity`. In fragment override `onAttach` function witch has activity as parameter. Save it as class member and you have callback to activity. Once user select answer call `callback.onAnswerSelected(questionId, answerId)`. To restore previous state add another function to your interface  `getSavedAnswer(int questionId)` Call it when you in `onActivityCreated()`. Now all you need some `HashMap` of answers in `Activity` that will save answers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It saves 3 pages, but it doesn't even remember the choice in those 3 pages it already saves. When I swipe to the second page, the first one is not destroyed, and despite that it does not remember its choice.

Comment: Actually in your newInstance you always create new instance of ArrayListFragment so, you always get new fragment. ViewPager will call getItem in any case. Save list of fragments in ViewPager adapter when you will cache all created fragments for particular num. But you will need to think about configuration change case when ViewPager will be recreated. So again, the example with saving data in activity will be better since you can override onSaveInstance function and save all answers

Answer (score 0):

It is reasonable why layout with checkboxes restores. Fragment can restore state of view in layout, if one has android:id attribute. But your listView does not restore state, cause it depends on your realization of adapter. You have to do it manually, for example: save state of selections from listView in onSaveInstanceState of Fragment and then get your selections from savedInstanceState, just like in Activity.